# mySQL query to get records closest to someone based on longitude and latitude without range

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table of users that I want other users to be able to search for each other by name. Generally this is easy to a point. However I want users with similar names to show up in order of proximity from one another so lets say therotically I am searching for "Mike" but I don't know his last name.. What I want my results to show is all the "Mike"'s in my database starting with the closest one first. I have longitude/latitude for all my users so thats not a problem the problem is the way my query is currently constructed I have to provide a specific range. So I am trying to figure out if theres another way I can construct the query to have no range specified so it will just go from closest to furthest.

Current query looks like

```
SELECT *,(((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($lon - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `memb_geo_locations` HAVING `distance` < $range ORDER BY `distance` ASC"
```

the flip side to this is also I am likely going to have to form an INNER JOIN with this as the names I'd be searching for are under a different table. where a member_id is the link between the 2 tables. the other table would have 
member_id, firstname, lastname
the geo table has 
member_id, longitude, latitude, primary

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  *,
  (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) 
    * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) 
    * cos((($lon - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM `memb_geo_locations` 
ORDER BY `distance` DESC
```

For the first part of your question just remove the HAVING and ORDER BY DESCending.

Adding the join should be straightforward enough:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  (((acos(sin(($lat*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($lat*pi()/180)) 
    * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) 
    * cos((($lon - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM memb_geo_locations 
INNER JOIN members ON members.member_id = memb_geo_locations.member_id
WHERE members.firstname LIKE 'bob or whatever%'
ORDER BY `distance` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the range you just ... exclude the range:

```
SELECT *,
      <distance_calculation> AS `distance` 
FROM `memb_geo_locations` 
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

To form an inner join you do it as you usually would.

```
SELECT ...
FROM memb_geo_locations
INNER JOIN other_table
 ON memb_geo_locations.member_id = other_table.member_id
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```